# Unable to take proper screenshot through Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, screenshot

I had wrote some code by python.

It is to capture web page.

But image has broken font.

This is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-iore
from selenium import webdriver
import json
import os, sys 
import re

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument("disable-gpu")

driver = webdriver.Chrome('[DRIVERPATH]', chrome_options=options)

driver.get("http://google.co.kr")
driver.set_window_size(500, 900)
screenshot = driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()
print screenshot

driver.quit()
```

This is resulten image:

[image]

How can I fix it?

---

*updated*

your advice is maximize screen. but font is still broken.

This is my fix code.

```
#driver.set_window_size(500, 900)
driver.maximize_window()
```

and capture image.

[image]

Comment: you want to capture the whole page ?

Comment: Try to maximize window size instead of setting `driver.set_window_size(500, 900)`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and this is how I solved it.

```
$ sudo apt-get install fonts-unfonts-core
$ sudo apt-get install fonts-unfonts-extra
```

If the system does not have fonts, the image can be broken.
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

After googling here and there, I found installing these three fallback fonts packages solves the text misrepresentation issue for majority of cases

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-indic
sudo apt-get install fonts-noto
sudo apt-get install fonts-noto-cjk
```

I found this article:
https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/5705492?hl=en

In case link goes down, here's the as it is copy

> It appears that Chrome in headless mode needs specific fonts installed
> for non-Latin characters. While this can be solved of course by
> installing a multitude of fonts, it would be a headache to install
> fonts for websites that support a lot of languages.
>
> Luckily there are modern font packs available that cover nearly all
> languages and scripts on earth. I have installed 3 font packs that now
> show non-Latin characters for a lot of languages. For India I
> installed a special font pack to cover all the languages and scripts
> in India. I also installed a special font pack that covers Chinese
> Simplified, Chinese Traditional, Japanese and Korean.
>
> Here are the 3 font packs that solve the issue. From top to bottom, an
> **Indian font pack, an international font pack and a font pack for**
> China, Japan and Korea:
>
> sudo apt-get install fonts-indic
> sudo apt-get install fonts-noto sudo
> apt-get install fonts-noto-cjk
>
> Installing these font packs solves the problem. And it does so
> elegantly. The normal Latin fonts used in the website's code still
> work, however when characters for a particular language can't be
> found, then headless Chrome falls back on the newly installed font
> packs.

Answer (score -1):

You need to take care of a couple of facts as follows:

- Always execute your `@Tests` with the *Browser Client* in a maximized mode.
- To maximize the *Chrome Browser* instead of using `maximize_window()` always use an instance of **`ChromeOptions()`**.
- To take a screenshot you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for  the *WebElements* to render witin the [**HTML DOM**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)
- Here is your own code block along with the above mentioned tweaks:

  ```
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-iore
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  import json
  import os, sys 
  import re

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('--headless')
  options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome('[DRIVERPATH]', chrome_options=options)
  driver.get("http://google.co.kr")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q")))
  screenshot = driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()
  driver.quit()
  ```

Comment: *"...instead of using maximize_window() always use an instance of ChromeOptions()"* any reason for this? Why not `driver.maximize_window()`?

Comment: Yeap, ChromeDriver team explicitly have kept an announcement that `maximize_window()` is still WIP.

Comment: @DebanjanB : Can you share the link for that announcement ?

Comment: @DebanjanB : Don't get offensive . All I am trying to get that link , so that I will also get to know about "announcement"